# couchdb: map in design document gives compilation_error

Tags: couchdb

I use Couchdb 1.1.1 in Debian testing

and I have this design document in database

```
{
 "_id": "_design/Page",
 "_rev": "9-1944cdebabf20ae569eab7b534b43e67",
 "views": {
     "all": {
         "map": "function(doc) {}"
     }
 },
 "language": "javascript"
}
```

but still I get in `http://localhost:5984/db_development/_design/Page/_view/all`

this `{"error":"compilation_error","reason":"Expression does not eval to a function. ((new String(\"function(doc) {}\")))"}`

I tried to run different simple map functions in spidermonkey-bin interpreter and they was loaded correctly, but same error in couchdb

I really can't see, where problem is....

Ok, in mailing list I found that it is needed to wrap function to parentheses "()", because something has changed in newer spidermonkey

So map function looks like this: `"map": "(function(doc) { emit([doc._id, doc._rev]);})"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, in mailing list I found that it is needed to wrap function to parentheses "()", because something has changed in newer spidermonkey

So map function looks like this: "map": "(function(doc) { emit([doc._id, doc._rev]);})"

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, be careful that the design doc is structured correctly. (I got a message like this because of a dumb error in my `shows` definition.)

Also, not sure this is a problem, but I don't think there should be a space before the curly brackets in the function definition.

Answer (score -4):

There is no return statement inside the map function.  Your map function needs to return something.

If you need to get a raw dump of all documents, there is a built-in feature for that: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#all_docs

Comment: I may change it to "function(doc){ emit(doc._id, doc._rev)}" or more complex function but still the same error

Comment: -1 because answer is just plain wrong. couchdb map functions don't need to return anything, further more, javascript functions don't need to return anything to be valid functions anyway.